# R add different column of a data frame to a single column

Tags: r, matrix, vector, dataframe, spss

I have a large data frame of 2050 rows by 202 columns. I read my data from SPSS with command `read.spss()`. These are factor variables.

```
data<-read.spss("filename.sav",to.data.frame=TRUE,reencode='utf-8')
dim(data)
[1] "data.frame"
dim(data)
[1] 2050  202
class(data[1,57])
[1] "factor"
class(data$aq21a) # data$aq21a is 57th column
[1] "NULL"
```

Now I want to add columns 57 to 61 `(data$aq21a,data$aq21b,data$aq21c,data$aq21d,data$aq21e)` to new variable `aq21` as follows

```
aq21<-rbind(data$aq21a,data$aq21b,data$aq21c,data$aq21d,data$aq21e)
```

But this does not give the required result. I want a 10250 by 1 vector

```
class(aq21)
[1] "matrix"
dim(aq21)
[1]    5 2050
```

The sample data is

```
head(data[,57:60])
               bq21a               bq21b               bq21c               bq21d
1 Rich / Independent           Efficient                <NA>                <NA>
2   Known / Familiar           Efficient                <NA>                <NA>
3  Relative / Friend Educated / Academic         Accountable                <NA>
4       Truthfulness           Behaviour          Good/Great Educated / Academic
5          Behaviour   Relative / Friend Educated / Academic    Known / Familiar
6          Behaviour   Relative / Friend                <NA>                <NA>
```

I want this type of result

```
               bq21a
1  Rich / Independent
2    Known / Familiar
3   Relative / Friend
4        Truthfulness
5           Behaviour
6           Behaviour
7           Efficient
8           Efficient
9 Educated / Academic
10          Behaviour
11  Relative / Friend
... and so on
```

Sample of the result i get, which is not as required

```
aq21[1:5,1:10]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]   11   24   19   35   22   22    3   22   NA     2
[2,]    6    6   18   22   19   19   31   31   NA     5
[3,]   NA   NA    9    2   18   NA   26   NA   NA    31
[4,]   NA   NA   NA   18   24   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
[5,]   NA   NA   NA   23   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
```

What is wrong with it and how can I get correct answer?

Comment: `melt` from "reshape2"? `unlist` from base R?

Comment: `aq21 <- data.frame(Col=unlist(data[,57:61]))`

Comment: @Prabhu  If you want to consider the row order, it may be better to use `data.frame(bq21a=c(t(data)))` as `unlist` will get you in the column order which I think is not you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the concerned columns are all `factors`, For example:

```
   data <- structure(list(bq21a = structure(c(4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Behaviour", 
   "Known / Familiar", "Relative / Friend", "Rich / Independent", 
   "Truthfulness"), class = "factor"), bq21b = structure(c(3L, 3L, 
   2L, 1L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Behaviour", "Educated / Academic", 
  "Efficient", "Relative / Friend"), class = "factor"), bq21c = structure(c(NA, 
   NA, 1L, 3L, 2L, NA), .Label = c("Accountable", "Educated / Academic", 
  "Good/Great"), class = "factor"), bq21d = structure(c(NA, NA, 
   NA, 1L, 2L, NA), .Label = c("Educated / Academic", "Known / Familiar"
   ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("bq21a", "bq21b", "bq21c", 
   "bq21d"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
   "4", "5", "6"))

   as.numeric(data[,1])
   #[1] 4 2 3 5 1 1
   as.numeric(data[,2])
   #[1] 3 3 2 1 4 4
   as.numeric(data[,3])
   #[1] NA NA  1  3  2 NA
```

When you do `rbind`, you are getting the result in the form of conversion from `factor` to `numeric` as shown above.

```
  rbind(data$bq21a, data$bq21b, data$bq21c, data$bq21d) 
  #    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
  #[1,]    4    2    3    5    1    1
  #[2,]    3    3    2    1    4    4
  #[3,]   NA   NA    1    3    2   NA
  #[4,]   NA   NA   NA    1    2   NA
```

You could use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` while reading the data with `read.csv` or `read.table`.  If that is the case:

```
 dat1 <- data.frame(bq21a=c(rbind(data$bq21a, data$bq21b, data$bq21c, data$bq21d)))
 head(dat1)
 #           bq21a
 #1 Rich / Independent
 #2          Efficient
 #3               <NA>
 #4               <NA>
 #5   Known / Familiar
 #6          Efficient
```

#### Update

Or try:

```
   dat2 <- data.frame(bq21a=c(t(data))) #wouldn't matter if the columns are `factors`
   #in your dataset the code would be
   #dat2 <- data.frame(bq21a= c(t(data[,57:61[)))  

   identical(dat1, dat2)
   #[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

as suggested by Ananda and akrun, I used following code

```
aq21<-data.frame(Col=unlist(data[,57:61]))
```

And this solved the problem. But I am still not getting why `rbind` does not work?

do we have to use `unlist` for `rbind` to work properly?